# How are the feeds on the v1.0 iOS app personalized?

Tags: support, ios-app, content, ios-app-feed, personalization

The [Stack Exchange blog announcement touts **the feed**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/) as something that can be / or is already "deeply personalized", but I'm not seeing any sort of settings to accomplish that within the app itself.

Specifically, I'm not aware of a manner to suppress a specific site (perhaps careers or english language) or the hot questions category entirely in my feed on the iOS app.

How can I shape what content I feel is relevant to me when using the iOS app version 1.0.x?

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstood [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/).

> At the heart of our mobile applications is The Feed which **gives you a
> deeply personalized selection of content** customized to what’s relevant
> to you.
>
> It includes any new answers, comments, or upvotes on your posts, and
> even new questions **we think you’d like based on your previous
> activity**. (emphasis added)

Note that it doesn't say it *can be* customized, but that it *gives you something which is* customized. It factors in what they know about you, and chooses posts automatically.

It would be great if we could customize it as you suggested, but it is currently not possible.

Comment: Agreed.  I very much would like to be able to customize the feed, but it doesn't seem to be able to.  Mine, at least, is not very personalized - and I'd think I am a great example of an 'easily personalized feed' person; over 90% of my answers are on questions that contain one tag, and I'm almost triple the next person's tag score in that tag.  My feed should be all questions from that tag, and yet it never has any questions from that tag unless I'd done something already on them.

Comment: I'm looking for what activity customizes the feed for me personally. I avoid hot questions like the plague on the site and don't really visit careers, so I want to know how to eliminate or minimize those items on a very small amount of screen space.  Basically the feed is so bad, I don't ever go use it.

Comment: @bmike I guess the misunderstanding was mine then. I'll leave this up for anyone looking for more direct control, but hopefully someone can help you out.

Comment: I've edited the title and post to make my question clearer. I do appreciate the answer and thoughts. My guess is internally, they hope for the feed to become highly personalized / personalizable, but for the 1.0 it appears to be lacking in personalization from what I've been able to test so far.

Comment: I dislike most everything I see in my feed on the iOS app. I regard the great majority of what I see there as "noise". I came here looking for a way to turn most of that off. Oh well, maybe in a future version?

Comment: Bump.  This is a serious issue for iOS app.  For now, I’m using the phone web browser instead.