# Is there an equivalent of the iOS app feed for the mobile website?

Tags: discussion, mobile-web, ios-app-feed

On the iOS app, when you select the menu button, on of the options besides selecting a specific SE site, is “Feed”.

This shows some suggested questions to check out plus recent responses to comments etc as well as a random HNQ and a link to the HNQ list.

Is there an equivalent of this on the mobile website?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is exclusive to the iOS and Android apps. From the [announcing blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/05/08/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/):

> At the heart of our mobile applications is **The Feed** which gives you a deeply personalized selection of content customized to what’s relevant to you.
>
> It includes any new answers, comments, or upvotes on your posts, and even new questions we think you’d like based on your previous activity.

The precise criteria for the selection aren't public (AFAIK), see e.g. [How are the feeds on the v1.0 iOS app personalized?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231350/295232). It's a combination of the following network-wide API calls:

- https://stackexchange.com/hot-questions-for-mobile
- [/inbox](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox)
- [/notifications](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/notification)

and a few site-specific ones, depending on your last activity / accounts with the most reputation / maybe even your "Your Communities" list? Otherwise I don't see why Cooking and English Language & Usage would be in your feed.

Comment: I do sometimes get random sites pop up in the feed that I have had minimal interaction with. Never understood why.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Stack Exchange homepage](https://stackexchange.com/) but it doesn't seem to have responsive design

Comment: I did look at that but there isn’t a mobile version of that page.